# Check if elements from different lists are in df column and append to another column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

I have a df like this:

| Casa | Name | Clase_jfs | Categoria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Just_For_Sports | mochila reebok active | ACCESORIOS | mochila |
| Just_For_Sports | tubo lejopi de pelotas softee | ACCESORIOS | tubo |
| Just_For_Sports | pack de medias puma x2 | ACCESORIOS | pack |
| Just_For_Sports | gorro adidas de natación 3 rayas | ACCESORIOS | natacion |

And 27 different Lists like these:

```
MODA=['mochila','wear', 'urban', 'pack']
TENIS=['tubo', 'raqueta','red']
NATACION=['natacion', 'pileta','tapon']
```

on the other hand I have an empty list:

```
intermedia1=[]
```

this is my current script:

```
for element in df_JFS['Categoria']:       
    if  element in VOLEY:
        intermedia1.append('VOLEY')
    elif element in UNIFORMES:
        intermedia1.append('UNIFORMES')
    elif element in TREKKING_OUTDOOR_ADVENTURE:
        intermedia1.append('TREKKING_OUTDOOR_ADVENTURE')        
    elif element in TRAINING:
        intermedia1.append('TRAINING')        
    elif element in TENIS:
        intermedia1.append('TENIS')        
    elif element in SURF:
        intermedia1.append('SURF')        
    elif element in SQUASH:
        intermedia1.append('SQUASH')  
    elif element in SKATEBOARD:
        intermedia1.append('SKATEBOARD')                    
    elif element in RUNNING:
        intermedia1.append('RUNNING')        
    elif element in RUGBY:
        intermedia1.append('RUGBY')
    elif element in PING_PONG:
        intermedia1.append('PING_PONG')
    elif element in PESAS:
        intermedia1.append('PESAS')
    elif element in PADDLE:
        intermedia1.append('PADDLE')
    elif element in NATACION:
        intermedia1.append('NATACION')
    elif element in MODA:
        intermedia1.append('MODA')
    elif element in INFANTIL:
        intermedia1.append('INFANTIL')
    elif element in HOCKEY:
        intermedia1.append('HOCKEY')
    elif element in HANDBALL:
        intermedia1.append('HANDBALL')
    elif element in GOLF:
        intermedia1.append('GOLF')
    elif element in FUTBOL:
        intermedia1.append('FUTBOL')
    elif element in FRONTON:
        intermedia1.append('FRONTON')
    elif element in CICLISMO:
        intermedia1.append('CICLISMO')
    elif element in BASQUET:
        intermedia1.append('BASQUET')
    elif element in BASICOS:
        intermedia1.append('BASICOS')
    elif element in BASEBALL_SOFTBALL:
        intermedia1.append('BASEBALL_SOFTBALL')
    elif element in ARTES_MARCIALES_Y_BOX:
        intermedia1.append('ARTES_MARCIALES_Y_BOX')
    elif element in AEROBICS_Y_FITNESS:
        intermedia1.append('AEROBICS_Y_FITNESS')
    else:
        intermedia1.append('OTROS')
        
df_JFS['Categoria']=intermedia1
```

How can it be done efficiently?

output should look like this:

| Casa | Name | Clase_jfs | Categoria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Just_For_Sports | mochila reebok active | ACCESORIOS | MODA |
| Just_For_Sports | tubo lejopi de pelotas softee | ACCESORIOS | TENIS |
| Just_For_Sports | pack de medias puma x2 | ACCESORIOS | MODA |
| Just_For_Sports | gorro adidas de natación 3 rayas | ACCESORIOS | NATACION |

df['Categoria'] value, should be the name of the list where the word was found

Thanks!

Comment: Insead of 27 lists, put them into a dictionary of  reverse map: `d = { 'mochila': 'MODA', 'wear': 'MODA', ...}` etc. And then do `df.Categoria.map(d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few approaches I would suggests

#### Approach 1

The complexity of finding something in a list is `O(n)`. it optimise that you can use a set instead which is `O(1)`.

```py
MODA = set(['mochila', 'wear', 'urban', 'pack'])
```

#### Approach 2

If all of the value of all the list is unique, you can create a `dict` that map values to key.
You can just write a loop to map value to key the result should be like below:

```py
{
 'mochila': "MODA",
 'wear': "MODA",
 'urban': "MODA",
 'pack': "MODA",
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the time efficiency, but if you want to prevent boilerplate coding, you can use `apply` function along with a few other steps:

```py
import pandas as pd
# Defining the lists of data(rest of the code)
# .
# .
myDict ={'MODA':MODA, "TENIS":TENIS, "NATACION":NATACION} 
def search(valueToSearch):
  for key, valuesList in myDict.items():
    if valueToSearch in  valuesList:
      return key
  return "Not Found"
df["Categoria"] = df["Categoria"].apply(search)
df
```

##### Output

|  | Casa | Name | Clase_jfs | Categoria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Just_For_Sports | mochila reebok active | ACCESORIOS | MODA |
| 1 | Just_For_Sports | tubo lejopi de pelotas softee | ACCESORIOS | TENIS |
| 2 | Just_For_Sports | pack de medias puma x2 | ACCESORIOS | MODA |
| 3 | Just_For_Sports | gorro adidas de natación 3 rayas | ACCESORIOS | NATACION |

Note that, you should define the `myDict` as shown above. If you have any other list, you should define them in `myDict` variable in the same way.